# How to get the path string from a java.nio.Path?

Tags: java, file, nio

Rewrote question with more info

I have some code that creates a `Path` object using relative paths, like this: `Paths.get("..", "folder").resolve("filename")`. Later, I want to get the path string "..\folder\filename" from it (I'm on windows, so backslashes). When I run this code using manual compile or from Eclipse, this works fine.

However, when I run it using Maven, it doesn't work any more. The `toString()` method returns `[.., folder, filename]` instead of an actual path string. Using `path.normalize()` doesn't help. Using `path.toFile().getPath()` does return what I'm looking for, but I feel there should be a solution using just the `nio.path` API.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Both `Paths.get("path/to/file").toString()` and `Paths.get("path", "to", "file").toString()` both return `"path/to/file"` for me.

Comment: Same is true of `Paths.get("path/to").resolve("file").toString()`, which returns `"path/to/file"`.

Comment: I may be wrong but for me both returns the same string !!!

Comment: What result do you see for `Paths.get("path", "to", "file").getClass().getName()`? Perhaps you're picking up a wonky FileSystem implementation.

Comment: The difference might be that I'm starting with going up one path (relative to working directory): `Paths.get("..", "path/to", "file")`. I didn't think it would be relevant to the question, but apparently it is.

Comment: Again, this doesn't result in anything surprising: `Paths.get("..", "path/to", "file").toString()` returns `"../path/to/file"`. I'm using JDK 1.7.0_21

Answer (score 68):

Use:

```
Paths.get(...).normalize().toString()
```

Another solution woul be:

```
Paths.get(...).toAbsolutePath().toString()
```

However, you get strange results: `Paths.get("/tmp", "foo").toString()` returns `/tmp/foo` here. What is your filesystem?

Comment: Updated question with more info on when this fails.

Comment: Are you sure this is java.nio.Paths that you use?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure :) `java.nio.file.Paths`, to be exact.

Answer (score 7):

To complete the the [fge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17552395/1763602), I would add some info:

1. `normalize()` simply removes redundant pieces of strings in your path, like `.`
   or `..`; it does **not** operate at the OS level or gives you an absolute path from a relative path
2. `toAbsolutePath()` on the contrary gives you what the name says, the absolute path of the `Path` object. But...
3. `toRealPath()` resolves also soft and hard links (yes they exists also on Windows, so win user, you're not immune). So it gives to you, as the name says, the *real* path.

So what's the best? It depends, but personally I use `toRealPath()` the 99% of the cases.

As pointed out by [Roberto Bonvallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552299/how-to-get-the-path-string-from-a-java-nio-path/68713421?noredirect=1#comment130880214_68713421), since `toRealPath()` throws an exception if the file does not already exist because, for example, you want to create it. In this case I prefer `toAbsolutePath()`.

Source: [Official javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

Comment: Note that `toRealPath` throws an exception if the file doesn't exist, which is not what you want when you are passing the path for a file yet to be created.

Comment: Thank you @RobertoBonvallet, I'll add it to the answer